# PowerShell script not working after update

Tags: powershell

I updated PS 1.0 to 4.0 and my script is not working.

It says:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method na
med 'op_Division'.
At C:\Users\sabrnpet\Documents\rsm-monitoring-killer.ps1:18 char:5
+ if ($test/1KB -ge $consumed)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Division:String) [], Runti 
   meException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Here is script:

```
### EDIT ME ####
$process = "opera" # BMCRSM
$consumed = 4500000 # in kilobytes
################

# checking if process is running
if (-not (Get-Process $process -ea 0) )
{
    Write-Host "Process $process is not running"
    Exit
}

# variables
$getProcess = Get-Process $process 

# checking if process eating much ram
if ($getProcess.WorkingSet64/1KB -ge $consumed)
{
    Write-Host "I will termiante it..."
    $getProcess.Kill()
}
else
{
    Write-Host "OK"
}
```

I undestand that there is problem with divison of kilobytes I think, but I need this value in kilobytes. So how to do It please?

Thanko you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
# variables
$getProcess = Get-Process "$process"
```

string variable must be in "quotes"

Answer (score 1):

Look at your error message:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'.
```

`[System.Object[]]` denotes an array.  `Get-Process` is finding more than one instance of Opera running.  You need to iterate through that array, and work on them one at a time:

```
# checking if process eating much ram

Foreach ($FoundProcess in $getProcess)
  {
   if ($FoundProcess.WorkingSet64/1KB -ge $consumed)
   {
    Write-Host "I will termiante it..."
    $FoundProcess.Kill()
   }


  else
  {
    Write-Host "OK"
  }
}
```